# Rails link_to with path, remote, class, id and block

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I'm trying to make a `link_to` with properties `some_path(@object), remote: true, class: "some class", id: "some id"` and a block, but any way fails.

```
<%= link_to some_path(@object), remote: true, class: "some-class", id: "object-<%=@object.id%>" do %>
Some html
<% end %>
```

Some help please, I'm trying not to do `url_for()` and partitionate the path, I want to use the path helper. As I mentioned I'd like to avoid this `url_for` [Syntax for link_to with block in rails3 with :remote=>true and including :class and :id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673738/syntax-for-link-to-with-block-in-rails3-with-remote-true-and-including-class)

The error I get is undefined "<", expecting key word end, that I get from the server running, because this html is rendered from a `.js.erb` file, in the browser it happens nothing because of that error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the `js.erb` template where this link is rendered?

Comment: i think you can use string interpolation for id  like `id: "object-#{@object.id}"`

Comment: maybe add a space on the id, though if you can post the stack trace that would help a lot